# JS slider has one too many slides. Can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, slider, carousel

I have a slider which is supposed to show only three slides, but it continues (both automatically or by click) to a fourth blank slide. I don't see where the number of slides is set in the code. Would really appreciate some educated eyes on this.

The JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var $slider = $(".slider"),
      $slideBGs = $(".slide__bg"),
      diff = 0,
      curSlide = 0,
      numOfSlides = $(".slide").length-1,
      animating = false,
      animTime = 500,
      autoSlideTimeout,
      autoSlideDelay = 6000,
      $pagination = $(".slider-pagi");
  
  function createBullets() {
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfSlides+1; i++) {
      var $li = $("<li class='slider-pagi__elem'></li>");
      $li.addClass("slider-pagi__elem-"+i).data("page", i);
      if (!i) $li.addClass("active");
      $pagination.append($li);
    }
  };
  
  createBullets();
  
  function manageControls() {
    $(".slider-control").removeClass("inactive");
    if (!curSlide) $(".slider-control.left").addClass("inactive");
    if (curSlide === numOfSlides) $(".slider-control.right").addClass("inactive");
  };
  
  function autoSlide() {
    autoSlideTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      curSlide++;
      if (curSlide > numOfSlides) curSlide = 0;
      changeSlides();
    }, autoSlideDelay);
  };
  
  autoSlide();
  
  function changeSlides(instant) {
    if (!instant) {
      animating = true;
      manageControls();
      $slider.addClass("animating");
      $slider.css("top");
      $(".slide").removeClass("active");
      $(".slide-"+curSlide).addClass("active");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $slider.removeClass("animating");
        animating = false;
      }, animTime);
    }
    window.clearTimeout(autoSlideTimeout);
    $(".slider-pagi__elem").removeClass("active");
    $(".slider-pagi__elem-"+curSlide).addClass("active");
    $slider.css("transform", "translate3d("+ -curSlide*100 +"%,0,0)");
    $slideBGs.css("transform", "translate3d("+ curSlide*50 +"%,0,0)");
    diff = 0;
    autoSlide();
  }

  function navigateLeft() {
    if (animating) return;
    if (curSlide > 0) curSlide--;
    changeSlides();
  }

  function navigateRight() {
    if (animating) return;
    if (curSlide < numOfSlides) curSlide++;
    changeSlides();
  }

  $(document).on("mousedown touchstart", ".slider", function(e) {
    if (animating) return;
    window.clearTimeout(autoSlideTimeout);
    var startX = e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,
        winW = $(window).width();
    diff = 0;
    
    $(document).on("mousemove touchmove", function(e) {
      var x = e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
      diff = (startX - x) / winW * 70;
      if ((!curSlide && diff < 0) || (curSlide === numOfSlides && diff > 0)) diff /= 2;
      $slider.css("transform", "translate3d("+ (-curSlide*100 - diff) +"%,0,0)");
      $slideBGs.css("transform", "translate3d("+ (curSlide*50 + diff/2) +"%,0,0)");
    });
  });
  
  $(document).on("mouseup touchend", function(e) {
    $(document).off("mousemove touchmove");
    if (animating) return;
    if (!diff) {
      changeSlides(true);
      return;
    }
    if (diff > -6 && diff < 6) {
      changeSlides();
      return;
    }
    if (diff <= -6) {
      navigateLeft();
    }
    if (diff >= 6) {
      navigateRight();
    }
  });
  
  $(document).on("click", ".slider-control", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("left")) {
      navigateLeft();
    } else {
      navigateRight();
    }
  });
  
  $(document).on("click", ".slider-pagi__elem", function() {
    curSlide = $(this).data("page");
    changeSlides();
  });
  
});
```

The HTML

```
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider-control left inactive"></div>
  <div class="slider-control right"></div>
  <ul class="slider-pagi"></ul>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide slide-0 active">
      <div class="slide__bg"></div>
      <div class="slide__content">
        <!--<svg class="slide__overlay" viewBox="0 0 720 405" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax slice">
          <path class="slide__overlay-path" d="M0,0 150,0 500,405 0,405" />
        </svg>-->
        <div class="slide__text">
          <h2 class="slide__text-heading"><b>New</b> featured products</h2>
          <h3 class="slide__text-sub-head">Ives<sup>®</sup> hands-free door pulls</h3>
          <p class="slide__text-desc">Ives offers hands-free pulls and door opening tools that enable pedestrians to operate the door with an arm or foot to avoid contacting surfaces with their hands. This is a cost-effective solution for retrofitting high-traffic mechanical applications to hands-free.<br><a class="slide__text-link">Learn More</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide-1 ">
      <div class="slide__bg"></div>
      <div class="slide__content">
        <!--<svg class="slide__overlay" viewBox="0 0 720 405" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax slice">
          <path class="slide__overlay-path" d="M0,0 150,0 500,405 0,405" />
        </svg>-->
        <div class="slide__text">
          <h2 class="slide__text-heading"><b>New</b> featured products</h2>
          <h3 class="slide__text-sub-head">LCN<sup>®</sup> touchless actuators</h3>
          <p class="slide__text-desc">Allegion offers no-touch actuators that are installed in place of push buttons and comply with ANSI 156.19 low energy standards. A pedestrian simply waves a hand in front of the wall plate, the technology senses the motion and acknowledges intent to enter. No contact with the door or hardware is required.<br><a class="slide__text-link">Learn More</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide-2">
      <div class="slide__bg"></div>
      <div class="slide__content">
        <!--<svg class="slide__overlay" viewBox="0 0 720 405" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax slice">
          <path class="slide__overlay-path" d="M0,0 150,0 500,405 0,405" />
        </svg>-->
        <div class="slide__text">
          <h2 class="slide__text-heading"><b>New</b> featured products</h2>
          <h3 class="slide__text-sub-head">Schlage<sup>®</sup> mobile access solutions</h3>
          <p class="slide__text-desc">Schlage Mobile Access Solutions provide comprehensive touchless offering, including mobile enabled multi-technology readers, mobile enabled wireless electronic locks and mobile access credentials.<br><a class="slide__text-link">Learn More</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TIA!

Comment: Don't know if this solves your problem, but I believe you're confusing length with index. This seems wrong: numOfSlides = $(".slide").length-1. It should be numOfSlides = $(".slide").length

Comment: @MannyAlvarado Thanks for your tip. I don't know enough to know whether your suggested code is right or not. But either way, It did not have the intended effect. Now instead of 1 extra blank slide it is showing 2 extra blank slides. So 5 in total, when there should only be 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the following which seems to have corrected the issue.

I changed this line:

numOfSlides = $(".slide").length-1,

To this:

numOfSlides = $(".slide").length-2,

Getting the desired result now...only 3 slides as intended. Hopefully the code is fundamentally sound.

Comment: Look at the amount of 'slide' classes you have. You should have only three if you have three slides. That way you won't need to do this. But good you solved your issue.